# elasticdump with TLS - unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, ssl

Using elasticsearch 7.9.3 with TLS security. I can connect to it via python, curl and openssl using the ca certificates I generated.

```
# These work, but this is a fake domain name
openssl s_client -connect node0:9200 -CAfile /etc/elasticsearch/certs/ca.pem
curl --cacert /etc/elasticsearch/certs/ca.crt -u "elastic:$ELASTIC_PASS" 'https://node0.elastic.test.com:9200/_cat/health'

# Node / elasticdump is not happy
$ elasticdump --input=./account_mapping.json --output="https://elastic:$ELASTIC_PASS@node0.elastic.test.com:9200/account" --type=mapping
Thu, 19 Nov 2020 21:28:50 GMT | starting dump
Thu, 19 Nov 2020 21:28:50 GMT | got 1 objects from source file (offset: 0)
Thu, 19 Nov 2020 21:28:50 GMT | Error Emitted => unable to verify the first certificate
Thu, 19 Nov 2020 21:28:50 GMT | Error Emitted => unable to verify the first certificate
Thu, 19 Nov 2020 21:28:50 GMT | Total Writes: 0
Thu, 19 Nov 2020 21:28:50 GMT | dump ended with error (get phase) => Error: unable to verify the first certificate

$ npm config set cafile /etc/elasticsearch/certs/ca.pem
# same result
Thu, 19 Nov 2020 21:28:50 GMT | dump ended with error (get phase) => Error: unable to verify the first certificate

$ elasticdump --input=../account_mapping.json --output="https://elastic:$ELASTIC_PASS@node1.elastic.test.com:9200/account" --type=mapping --output-ca=/etc/elasticsearch/certs/ca.pem
# same result
```

Other posts suggested running with NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0, but that did not fix the problem in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works if you provide tlsAuth AND output-ca flags.

```
$ elasticdump --input=./account_mapping.json --output="https://elastic:$ELASTIC_PASS@node0.elastic.test.com:9200/account" --type=mapping --tlsAuth --output-ca=/etc/elasticsearch/certs/ca.pem
```